# How can I get a confirmation email when the other party has received and when they have read my email?

Tags: email

I want to know how can I get a confirmation email when the other party has received and when they have read my email ?

I use Roundcube as email reader/sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [list of services](http://email.about.com/od/windowsreturnreceipts/tp/certified_email.htm) that claim to do that. Never used any of them, so I can't tell how good they are.